# InputStream of a socket not readable

Tags: java, sockets, post, encoding, outputstream

I have an HTML form that makes a POST request to a Socket I made with Java. I read each line with

```
 /**
 * Read a line from an {@link InputStream}
 * @param inFromClient The {@link InputStream} to read from
 * @return The {@link String} read
 * @throws IOException When something went wrong while reading
 */
private String readLine(InputStream inFromClient) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder lineb = new StringBuilder();
    char c = (char) inFromClient.read();
    while (c != '\n'){
        lineb.append(Character.toString(c));
        c = (char) (inFromClient.read());        
    }
    String line = lineb.toString();
    return line.substring(0,line.lastIndexOf('\r')<0?0:line.lastIndexOf('\r'));
}
```

That way, I'm able to parse the request till the boundary and then save the file sent. Everything works perfectly.

However, I'm also trying to make a POST request with Java to the same socket. First, I create a second socket connected to my server socket. Then I do:

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
pw.println("POST / HTTP/1.1");
pw.println("Host: ...");
...
```

### The problem

The problem is, my method cannot read any line and it all ends up with a "OutOfMemory' exception at line 5. Why am I not able to read lines sent from a Java socket while I can read those sent from my browser (html form) ? Thank you.

Comment: Why do you append `Character.toString()`? A `StringBuilder` has an .append() method accepting a `char` as an argument...

Comment: Yes you're right, but that doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server code must read() into an int and check whether that's -1 before casting to a char. You're ignoring end-of-file from the stream and appending -1 to your string builder for ever.

However:

1. I'd recommend using an existing HTTP server framework in your server to read and parse requests, rather than writing your own. (Or at least use an off-the-shelf HTTP request parser / response serialiser if you want to use your own socket code.)
2. Both your client and server code ignore character encoding. You need to convert bytes to/from chars using a Charset instance.
3. Use HttpURLConnection in your client, rather than a simple TCP socket.
4. Better, use something like https://hc.apache.org/ for your HTTP functionality.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Which framework would you recommend me to use? I need a parser that can detect the boundary during the reception then save the uploaded file with a FileOutputStream. I don't want to wait till the end of upload. Actually I'm builder a streaming system (streaming from a web page or an Android app).
Moreover, as I'm only uploading files (binary data), I don't understand with character encoding is needed.
Thank you!

Comment: Not clear whether your web server is on Android or not. If not, and you want to use Java, then I'd use a servlet container like Jetty or Tomcat to handle HTTP for me. 

I've used commons-fileupload to handle binary uploads. Again, I'd use a library to handle the multipart stuff rather than implementing it myself.

Comment: Character encoding: the HTTP request, headers and response headers are textual. You're generating the POST request with a PrintWriter using the default character set (rather than explcitly using US-ASCII or UTF-8), and casting bytes directly to chars in the server, which assumes that your server's default character encoding is also ASCII-ish.

Despite appearances, HTTP (plus multipart etc.) is a pretty complex protocol, and difficult to implement correctly.

Comment: My webserver is on a Raspberry Pi, and my client is either on Android (second socket), or on a PC (web page, POST http from html form). Tomcat doesn't allow me to handle the request directly during reception.